# Interrupt a thread waiting for user input

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    public class InterruptedInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputThread th=new InputThread();  //worker thread instantiated.
        th.start();  //worker thread start.
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);  //main thread sleep for 5 sec.
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
        th.interrupt();  //worker thread interrupted.
    }
}

class InputThread extends Thread{
    int sum;
    BufferedReader br;
    public void run(){
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            sum();
            sleep(10000);  //worker thread sleep for 10 sec.
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("sum="+sum);
        }
    }

    public void sum(){
        try{
            while(!isInterrupted()){
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

In this program, the worker thread waiting for the input by the user (which will be an integer value) and sum up until the *main thread* `interrut()` it.
But when the *main thread* `interrupt()` the `worker thread` its on I/O for user input and not interrupting.

The output I want to come up with this program is:
when the program executed, user have to input the integer values and after five sec. the sum of the input values is printed either the user still inputing the values or waiting for 5sec gone off. The result will be printed right after the 5th sec.

Comment: I believe your problem is that br.readLine() will execute before the boolean for the loop is reevaluated. Meaning that you will have to enter 1 number after the loop has expired

Comment: @jozefg: you are right. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the problem with this code is the fact that the statement `br.readLine()` must be executed before the loop conditional is checked. So to avoid this I would have 3 threads potentially.

Thread 1:

This would be the main or parent thread. In this thread you will merely count to 5 and then interrupt thread 2.

Thread 2:

In this thread you will monitor the static variable: `count`,then print it and interrupt thread 3 when interrupted.

Thread 3:

Here is were you would get input and and pass the input into a function which would add it to `count`. When interrupted do nothing.

If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since the IO is non-interruptable you can `@Override` the InputThread to close the input stream

```
@Override
public void interrupt(){
   try{ 
       this.br.close();
   }finally{
       super.interrupt();
   }
}
```

Comment: the output is not as it was supposed. Please check the above code.

Comment: You shouldnt catch and swallow the IOException in your sum() method.  Remove that try/catch and propogate the Exception inline with the method declaration.

Comment: @John Vint: I followed the same intuition as you in my (now deleted) answer, which was to close the BufferedReader asynchronously from the main thread and cause an IOException, but for some reason it does not seem to work. The call to br.close() blocks indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to allow the count to be printed at any time. Add the following to the InputThread Class:

```
private AtomicInt count;

public int getCount() {
   return count;
}
```

And have the main method print the count:

```
    System.out.println("Sum:" + th.getCount());
```

This would avoid any need for interupting threads.

Comment: sorry! but i need it to be using the `interrupt()`