# Interrupt a thread waiting for user input and then exit the app

Tags: java, multithreading, input, concurrency, thread-safety

I have two threads running, `userInputThread` waits for user input from the command line and `interrupterThread` tries to interrupt `userInputThread` 1 sec after starting. Obviously you cannot interrupt a thread that is blocked by the `System.in`. Another answer suggests to close `System.in` with `System.in.close()` before interrupting a thread. But when I run the following code, the `userInputThread` never gets interrupted and the app just hangs without closing.

```
class InputInterruptionExample {

    private Thread userInputThread;
    private Thread interrupterThread;

    InputInterruptionExample() {
        this.userInputThread = new Thread(new UserInputThread());
        this.interrupterThread = new Thread(new InterrupterThread());
    }

    void startThreads() {
        this.userInputThread.start();
        this.interrupterThread.start();
    }
    private class UserInputThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("enter your name: ");
                String userInput = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    private class InterrupterThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("about to interrupt UserInputThread");
                System.in.close();
                userInputThread.interrupt();
                userInputThread.join();
                System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputInterruptionExample exampleApp = new InputInterruptionExample();
        exampleApp.startThreads();
    }
}
```

There's already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997310/interrupt-a-thread-waiting-for-user-input), but there aren't any definite answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has solved the problem:

```
class InputInterruptionExample {

    private UserInputThread userInputRunnable;
    private Thread userInputThread;
    private Thread interrupterThread;

    InputInterruptionExample() {
        this.userInputRunnable = new UserInputThread();
        this.userInputThread = new Thread(userInputRunnable);
        this.interrupterThread = new Thread(new InterrupterThread());
    }

    void startThreads() {
        this.userInputThread.start();
        this.interrupterThread.start();
    }
    private class UserInputThread implements Runnable {
        private InputStreamReader isr;
        private BufferedReader br;

        UserInputThread() {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("enter your name: ");
                try{
                    String userInput = br.readLine();
                } catch(NullPointerException e) {}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        public void closeBufferdReader() {
            try {
                System.in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong in closeBufferdReader() method");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    private class InterrupterThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                userInputRunnable.closeBufferdReader();                 
                userInputThread.interrupt();
                userInputThread.join();
                System.out.println("Successfully interrupted");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputInterruptionExample exampleApp = new InputInterruptionExample();
        exampleApp.startThreads();
    }
}
```

**Update:** This only works when BufferedReader is split up this way:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String userInput = br.readLine();
```

For some reason the interruption does not seem to work when the readLine() structure is written as a oneliner:

```
this.userInput = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
```

So while it is possible to interrupt the thread in the split-up BufferedReader structure, it is now impossible to read user's input.

If someone could show a way to be able to get user input as well as interrupt the UserInputThread when the user doesn't provide any input in time (while interrupter is sleeping), please do.

Comment: Very cool.  Force an NPE by closing the stream. +1 for you sir.

Comment: @user1121883 you are right. For some reason I thought you cannot just interrupt() a thread blocked by System.in. hmm...

Comment: This is not correct. `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)` -- this does not initialize `userInputThread.br` but hides it so it is never initialized and the `userInputThread` is finished with NullPointerException. If you insert e.printStackTrace() you may see that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

All of my research leads me to believe that the underlying .read() in the .readLine() call cannot be interrupted (Without destroying the Process that System.in is attached to, at least).  The only other choices at that point is to use a polling IO scheme or switch to NIO.

Here's a quick (and very dirty/ugly) adaptation of your code into a polling IO scheme.  It's not an interupt solution so it's not directly answering your question, but rather hopefully getting you the behavior you desire.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class InputInterruptionExample {

    private UserInputThread uiThreadObj = null;
    private Thread inputThread = null;
    private Thread interrupThread = null;

    public InputInterruptionExample() {
        this.uiThreadObj = new UserInputThread();
        this.inputThread = new Thread(this.uiThreadObj);
        this.interrupThread = new Thread(new InterrupterThread());
    }

    void startThreads() {
        this.inputThread.start();
        this.interrupThread.start();
    }

    private class UserInputThread implements Runnable {
        private final AtomicBoolean runCmd = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        public void run() {
            try {
                final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                System.out.println("enter your name: ");
                while (this.runCmd.get()) {
                    if (System.in.available() > 0) {
                        String userInput = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("You typed: " + userInput);
                        System.out.println("enter your name: ");
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(5); //minimal sleep to prevent CPU peg
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Finishing normally.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("What'd you do?!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public final void requestStop() {
            this.runCmd.set(false);
        }
    }
    private class InterrupterThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
                System.out.println("Requesting that UserInputThread stop.");
                uiThreadObj.requestStop();
                System.out.println("Request made.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops..somethign went wrong.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputInterruptionExample exampleApp = new InputInterruptionExample();
        exampleApp.startThreads();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your example and it hangs just as well. `interrupThread` should've stopped `inputThread` and the app should've quit. Thanks for the attempt, but your answer didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting.  "Works for me" is applicable here, but I really wonder why it's hanging on your machine.  What line is it hanging on?

Comment: it hangs at 'enter your name:' line.

Comment: Very strange!  It hangs on a System.out call?

Comment: it prints out 'enter your name:' and then the app just hangs and never exits.