# NoSuchElementException after closing system.in

Tags: java, exception, io

[ [Interrupt a thread waiting for user input and then exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477978/interrupt-a-thread-waiting-for-user-input-and-then-exit-the-app) ]

I wanted to do the same exercise as mentioned in the above link. But, I ran into `NoSuchElementException` when I tried to use `inConsole.nextLine()`, after successfully closing `BufferedReader object`, in spite of reassigning `inConsole` like `inConsole = new Scanner(System.in)` to read from Standard input.

After closing `BufferedReader object`, can't I reassign to Scanner object like above and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never close neither `System.in` nor `System.out`. This will work and cause some strange effects. Actually you will never be able to read or write to SYSIN of SYSOUT respectively. Find other solution.

If you need advise how to solve your problem without closing `System.in` please provide more information about lifecycle of your application and probably send relevant code snippets.